# Hiding columns in a datatable - Shiny

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, subset, shinydashboard

I'm building a shiny App with a reactive dataset, which is output into: (1) *plot* and (2) a *datatable* (please see code below). 
I've successfully pulled the data through. However, I'm having trouble hiding certain variables (or columns) in the datatable and I have a small aesthetics issue.

I'm using a large dataset composed of 69 variables. When filtered using the three dropdownMenu inputs (see code below), the reactive dataset is then fed into the plot, which shows the number of commercial services (y) by their overall rating (x) - which is great.

However, I have two problems relating to the reactive dataset and the datatable output:

(a) In my Datatable tab, I want to select the first 8 variables of my dataset to be visible and the other 61 to be hidden. I've attempted to limit the list with some code (see Server output), but the datatable just doesn't load.

(b) When I select the Datatable tab, the variable name boxes are disproportiantely large (see image below for furth clarif.) I haven't attempted to address this issue, as I have no idea what the issue could be.

Help would be much appreciated.

PS. If it's necessary I can give more details on the data, it's so large it's difficult to give the structure etc.

**UI**

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
 titlePanel("Test App"),
 sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(id = "sidebar",
               uiOutput("geography1"),
               uiOutput("geography2"),
               uiOutput("service"),
     mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                    tabPanel("Visual", plotOutput("plot", height = "500px")),
                    tabPanel("Underlying data", dataTableOutput("table"))
        )
     )
  )
  )
  )
```

**Server**

```
    server <- function(input, output) {
   output$geography1 = renderUI({
      selectInput(inputId = "geog1",
                  label = "Select geography (higher):", 
                  choices = as.character(unique(Test$Geog1)),
                  selected = "Region")
   })
   datasub <- reactive({
      req(input$geog1)
      filter(Test, Geog1 %in% input$geog1)
   })

   output$geography2 = renderUI({
      selectInput(inputId = "geog2", 
                  label = "Select geography (lower):", 
                  choices = unique(datasub()[,"Geog2"]),
                  selected = unique(datasub()[,"Geog2"])[1]) 
   })
   datasub2 <- reactive({
      req(input$geog2)
      filter(datasub(), Geog2 %in% input$geog2)
   })

   output$service = renderUI({
      selectInput(inputId = "service",
                  label = "Select Service Type:",
                  choices = unique(datasub2()[,"Sub_type"]),
                  selected = unique(datasub2()[,"Sub_type"])[1])
   })
   datasub3 <- reactive({
      req(input$geog2)
      filter(datasub2(), Sub_type %in% input$service)

   })

   # Plot
   output$plot = renderPlot({

      plot(datasub3(), x = Overall_rating, locations = y)

   })

   # Generate an data table view of the data ----
   output$table <- renderDataTable({
      data.table(datasub3(),options=list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(9:69))))
   }) 

      shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Aesthetic issue with datatable**
[image: Aesthetic issue with datatable]

Comment: it looks like your column names are long and when data table wraps the text they end up expanding vertically. I would subset/select your data table like this `datasub3()[, 1:9]` and drop the `options` arg in your `renderDataTabe({})`

Comment: Thank you very much Nate - that's clear and concise, worked a treat!